# Difference between Isothermal and Free Expansion

Tags: thermodynamics

I just don't get the exact difference between isothermal expansion and free expansion: in free expansion there is no work done since there is no external external pressure. As to the case of isothermal expansion there is no pressure applied, then how is work said to be done in that case?

Comment: Well in free expansion, the external pressure is zero. In case of isothermal expansion, we are not changing the external pressure. Rather, we  let the heat supplied go directly into the form of work. The expression for work is $P\triangle V$. Thus, you can see in the case of free expansion, the work done is zero as the external pressure is zero. For isothermal expansion, the external pressure is constant, not necessarily zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In free expansion there is no work done as there is no external external pressure.

That's certainly true, in fact **free expansion** is an irreversible process in which a gas expands into an insulated evacuated chamber, you can think of it like ann container with a piston and the gas is left to expand in vacuum.

Hence, it is evident that $P_{ext}=0$ during the expansion, so the $W=0$. Now for a ideal gas this process occurs quickly so there is not temperature rise as well, so $dT=0$, so as per first law of thermodynamics $Q=0=W$ and since internal energy is only a function of temperature, so $dU=0$ as well.

So that was for free expansion.

Now for isothermal expansion:

Here if we see and characterise the states after and before isothermal expansion we can see: $$T_1=T_2$$ but other quantities differ,like the external pressure is constant, not necessarily zero.

Hence work done can be given by:

$$W_{1 \rightarrow 2}=- \int_{1}^{2}pdV$$ and as $$p=\frac{nRT}{V}$$

Work done can be given as,
$$W_{1 \rightarrow 2}=- \int_{1}^{2}\frac{nRT}{V}dV$$
$$W_{1 \rightarrow 2}=-nRT ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$$

And hence, work done differs in case of isothermal expansion as compared to that of free expansion.

Comment: hmm..so ritvik coudary u say that there is no heat gained in the case of free expansion ..then if there is no temperature change then how would the gas expand

Comment: and if the gas takes some heat energy Q to expand then it must result in a change internal energy U or work done W because Q=U+W

Comment: @BhargavaSisirKurella there is no relation between the temperature change and expansion of the gas, that is even if temperature doesn't change the gas can expand.

Comment: In the case of free expansion for ideal gases, which is an **irreversible process**, **no heat is taken in or given out** and also there is **no temperature change**, hence the result. Also see [Joule Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion)

Answer (score -3):

There is no concept of temperature here because the initial condition of free expansion is assumed if the system is properly insulated that means, there is no heat interaction between system and surrounding is permitted, however in my personal opinion the temp of system will try to change during this rapid process, but as the system is insulated, no heat transfer will take place and in the end there will be no change in internal energy of the system.

I hope some of you may correct me.

Thanks